# vs 2010 pro View Call Hierarchy does not work

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, ide

I am using C++ in Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 professional on Windows 7 64 bit.

It seems the View Call Hierarchy function does not work on this machine, which I used frequently on other machines... I have no idea why it does not work now...

When I right-click a method, and click "View Call Hierarchy", the hierarchy does not show in the corresponding tab; actually nothing happens there...

Has anyone encountered this before? How can I find this function back? Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to delete your intellisense files and start visual studio again?

Comment: @EtienneCordonnier how do i remove the intellisense files? what are they?

Comment: The .js files in your project folder, "intellisense" is used by visual studio to parse your files and some information is saved in those files. Sometimes this information get corrupted and it can help to delete them manually to have a new fresh file.

Comment: @EtienneCordonnier it seems there is not such files with extension .js in my project foler... would this be possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to delete the Intellisense files, sometimes it's the problem when things like "go to definition" or "view call hierarchy" stop functionning correctly. You can delete the .sdf files, and the IPCH folder, then start your project again.